# Segmentation fault in assembly code when using immediates

Tags: assembly, x86

So I've been learning some basic assembly code, oriented at making shellcode, and that's all fine and dandy, but the book I'm reading all of this on is a little dated. So far, the assembly code section has been working smoothly, but I've run into a problem with some of the code that opens a new shell.

```
BITS 32

  jmp short two     ; Jump down to the bottom for the call trick
one:
; int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv [], char *const 
envp[])
  pop ebx           ; ebx has the addr of the string
  xor eax, eax      ; put 0 into eax
  mov [ebx+7], al   ; null terminate the /bin/sh string
  mov [ebx+8], ebx  ; put addr from ebx where the AAAA is
  mov [ebx+12], eax ; put 32-bit null terminator where the BBBB is
  lea ecx, [ebx+8]  ; load the address of [ebx+8] into ecx for argv ptr
  lea edx, [ebx+12] ; edx = ebx + 12, which is the envp ptr
  mov al, 11        ; syscall #11
  int 0x80          ; do it

two:
  call one          ; Use a call to get string address
  db '/bin/sh'     ; the XAAAABBBB bytes aren't needed
```

After running through a couple test programs a couple times, I've managed to hone in on what I think is the problem. The first time it uses an immediate in the program, `[ebx+7]` (and so theoretically, the other two `mov` commands), cause a segmentation fault. I just can't understand why. The system call I'm trying to do (if the comments aren't that well in context) is `execve`, which takes a filename, a pointer to an array of arguments, and the `envp` variables. Is what this code is trying to do even possible anymore, and if not, how can I achieve the same affect?

The book, if your wondering, is "Hacking: the art of exploitation, 2nd edition", and it was made in 2008, so like I said, dated.

Comment: How are you assembling and linking and then testing this? Do you convert it to a shellcode string and insert it in a _C_ program?

Comment: `mov [ebx+7], al` isn't an immediate.  `mov al, 11` has an immediate source.  Anyway, if you assemble this into a normal executable, the string will be in the read-only `.text` section along with the code, so trying to write there will fault.

Comment: If you assemble and run this directly, this won't work as the text segment is read-only, thus `mov [ebx+7], al` crashes the program trying to write to the text segment.  You need to put this into a section that is both write- and executeable.

Comment: I'm using nasm and ld to run the code.@fuz Is there a way to get it to run in a write and executable segment, that would work with the idea of shellcode? can I just use 'section .[segment]'?

Comment: Easiest way without changing the code is to add the `-N` option to the linker (`ld`) command line.

Comment: @Michael what if I wanted to execute through a C program? while I test it using nasm and ld, my eventual goal is to use it in a program.

Comment: @AntonRobotron Pass `-Wl,-N` to the C compiler when linking.  There are other ways that are more involved, but in general you should not write code like this.